# Charging card multiple times

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi I integrated **Stripe** in my application to sell some paid registrations. In my stripe dashboard I have already created some **Coupons** some have percent off and some flat value off. I need to charge my customers in multiple currencies.
**I have issue in charging the customer.**
Let say I have a plan for $348/year and provided

1. Customer C1 a coupon CP1 having flat $347 off (so the charge value would be just $1)
2. Customer C2 a coupon CP2 having 50% off (so the charge value would be $174)

In case 2 there is no issue and the invoice is created.
but In case 1, it charges 2 times:

- First for $1 (the discounted value)
- Whole amount $348 (dont know why this gets charged)

Here is my code below:

---

Plan value updated (coupon applied which has "certain amount off)

```html
$cc = $_POST['coupon'];
$actual_amount = $_POST['actual_amount'];
$cpnObj = \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve($cc);
$cpnDtl = $cpnObj->getLastResponse()->json;
if($cpnDtl['id']){
 $amount_off = $cpnDtl['amount_off'];
 $percent_off = $cpnDtl['percent_off'];
 
 if ($amount_off) {
  $discount = $amount_off/100;
  $paymoney = $actual_amount - $discount; 
 }

 if ($percent_off) {
  $discount = $actual_amount * $percent_off/100;
  $paymoney = $actual_amount - $discount;                
 }
}
```

Later on through some session variable I use this disocunted amount to charge customer's card

```html
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];  
$plan_id = $_POST['plan_id'];
  
//Creating Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
 "description" => "creating the customer",
 "email" => "myemail@somedomain.com",
 "source" => $token // obtained with Stripe.js
]);

//If Merchant account is created at Stripe end, Charge his Card
if($customer->id != ''){
 $chargeCard = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  "amount" => $paymoney (calculated above after applying the promo-code),
  "currency" => 'USD',
  "description" => "subscription for a year",
  "capture" => true,
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "receipt_email" => "myemail@somedomain.com",
  "statement_descriptor" => "card is charged for so and so ... "
 ]);
}

//If Card is charged successfully, create the Merchant's Subscription at Stripe end
if($chargeCard->id != ''){
 $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "items" => [
      [
       "plan" => $plan_id,
      ],
    ],
  "billing" => "charge_automatically",
  "cancel_at_period_end" => false
 ));
}
```

I read into the doc here https://stripe.com/docs/api/ that while creating a Charge or Customer "**Source**" is optional parameter. Is this the matter of "**Source**"? Also into the doc "*creating a customer*" says that

> You must provide a source if the customer does not already have a
>   valid source attached, and you are subscribing the customer to be
>   charged automatically for a plan that is not free.

so can i use the SAME "**Source**" while creating the customer and creting the charge object?

Can you please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the combination of charge and subscription code you have there that's causing the double charge. You issue a one-off charge first. That succeeds and looking at the code then it kicks off a subscription payment right away. Is there a specific reason why you'd charge the card AND create a subscription?

Because I don't think you need that first charge created at all, furthermore you could use the [coupons directly on the subscription creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-coupon):

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    "coupon" => $cc,
    "items" => [
                    [
                        "plan" => $plan_id,
                    ],
            ],
    "billing" => "charge_automatically",
    "cancel_at_period_end" => false
));
```

So you don't need that calculation bit in the beginning.

As for your question around the source (stored card, bank account, etc): When you use the customer object it automatically will use the default source from it. Unless they have more cards stored and they select one to be used, you do not need to specify it.

Comment: Hi Mate thanks for your reply and sorry for my late reaction. If this is the case because of "combination of charge and subscription" then I am not sure why it is working right in case of 50% discount, it should have the issues in that case also.

You approach is good to club those 2 things (Subscription and charge the card) but here, in this case, I think I will not be able to get the charge_id (starts with ch_) as a response. I can get only the subscription id (starts with sub_).

Comment: Hi @user2811 that's correct, you only get the sub id. However if you have a webhook endpoint setup you can [get the charge details from the event.data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object) if you listen for the [charge.succeeded](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.succeeded) event type.